# I was required to write a python program which check each letter and if it is in upper case it converts into lower case and similarly vice versa

Tags: python, swap

**Swap function**
I was required to write a python program which check each letter and if it is in upper case it converts into lower case and similarly vice versa

```py
def swap_case(s):
    new_word = ""
    for letter in s:
        if letter.isupper():
            letter.lower()
            new_word = new_word + letter   
        elif letter.islower():
            letter.upper()
            new_word = new_word + letter
        else:
            new_word = new_word + letter        
    return new_word

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    result = swap_case(s)
    print(result)
``
```

Comment: `letter.lower()` and `letter.upper()` don't change `letter`, because strings are immutable.  They *return* the modified string, but since you don't capture it anywhere it's lost forever.

Comment: Why not just use `s.swapcase()`?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through every char of string and check if it is in upeer case then convert it to lower case with the **.lower()** function of string and vise versa
You can try This:

```
input_str = "Test sTring"
output_str=""
for char_data in input_str:
    if(char_data.isupper()):
        output_str+=char_data.lower()
    else:
        output_str+=char_data.upper()
print(output_str)
```

Output:

```
tEST StRING
```

Comment: @Mark Ransom
 am doing my home work to find solution for them